# Wrong images used as thumbnails by AdSense matched content

Tags: google-adsense, images, thumbnail

The AdSense Matched Content options displayed on my site seem to be pulling random images from the respective content and using those images as thumbnails.

In some cases, AdSense gets it right and uses a relevant image. But in other cases AdSense uses something nonsensical like a background image, a navigational element or a loosely-related image from lower in an article.

How can I designate which image AdSense uses for the Matched Content thumbnails? I tried using Opengraph meta `og:image` protocol, but AdSense seems to ignore it. How can I get AdSense to display the right Matched Content thumb?

Comment: Why did you just revert the proper capitalization of "AdSense" and add back in "thanks"?   Posts here are expected to use proper spelling and grammar while keeping fluff to a minimum.   Greetings, signatures, and thanks are not appropriate in questions here.

Comment: I did? I edited a grammatical mistake. It was not my intention to un-change your edits. Apologies. Is that why you downvoted me? Sigh. I'll try somewhere else.

Comment: I'm glad to hear it was just a mistake.  I re-applied all the edits, including your grammar edit and took the liberty of un-deleting this for you.